Patching ubuntu debian package
I am attempting to patch up a debian package for my own personal use. Previously I was using a tutorial based on this (what looks to be an updated guide): https://ubuntu-packaging-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ubuntu-packaging-guide/fixing-a-bug-example.html
The previous version of it I believe suggested using edit-patch to start up a new shell to perform edits so that they could be saved to debian/patches/series .. however, that example no longer exists and I can't recall how to do it.  (When I type edit-patch somenewpatch, it does not spawn the new shell like it would have previously and saved the changes to debian/patches and debian/patches/series).
What was the method to do that? I don't need submittodebian since I'm only going to place it in my own .deb repository
